# OS X 10.9 Mavericks does not show a menu bar

Tags: java, menubar, osx-mavericks

I just upgraded to Mac OS X 10.9 GM Mavericks. I also installed the latest JRE from Apple *and* Oracle and the latest version of Aptana Studio 3.

When starting AS3, the application appears without a menubar. There is only the main window.

Can I fix this somehow?

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_04"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-b21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0-b21, mixed mode)
```

Aptana Studio 3.4.2.

Comment: On my machine (an AIR) Aptana nor PHPStorm appears afters installing Mavericks.

Comment: Installing the latest JVM solved the problem here.

Comment: Still happening here. Updating the JVM doesn't work, and both Titanium and Aptana3 are updated. Besides, Aptana3 seems kind of abandoned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's a new version that fixes it, refer this page: http://www.aptana.com/news

The actual download link didn't work for me, I found it here:
http://preview.appcelerator.com/studio/

Answer (score 0):

Try removing Java 7 and install Java 6 from Apple's latest official package:
http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US